# This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've tried many way to solve this

1 - style change Theme

2 - File-> invalid cache and restart etc

but this all way did not work for me .Kindly share your knwoledge

my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yousa.myapplication3.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your XML?

Comment: of course but the problem is in contraint layout

Comment: Did you see my Ui image

Comment: i work on latest version 3.0 butt these problem not sort out  above is my xml

Comment: version 26.0.0 
still error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set constraints for the button as well, otherwise it'll keep jumping to different areas as told in the warning.